# VSTO AssemblyResolve issue

Tags: .net, vsto, assemblyresolve

We develop a VSTO plugin for Word and we have the problem that the earliest entry point of the addin is the AddIn_Startup handler. The issue is that this handler is called too late for the AssemblyResolve handler we implemented to find the needed assemblies.

I sovled the problem by assigning the handler to the AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve event in the Addins.Designer.cs class, but as you all know, this code is autogenerated.

Is there a way to assign the AssemblyResolve Handler sooner as in the AddIn_Startup handler and in a not autogenerated file?

Answer (score 0):

Be aware, you develop a add-in, not a standalone applicaton where you can manage references at runtime and do whatever you need. You may consider adding the binding information to the application config file (in your case it will be Word.exe.config).

Comment: This is not a solution, because we can't deploy a Word.exe.config to every client.

Comment: There is no other way.

Answer (score 0):

You can add handler in AddIn_Startup code. Code is in VB.net.

```
AddHandler AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve, AddressOf AssemblyResolver
```

Answer (score 0):

I have just had this problem, landed here from searching and then had a look around the  [VSTO Microsoft.Tools AddinBase Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.tools.addinbase?view=vsto-2017) (I hope this is the right link).  In any case I am Overriding the Begininit and setting AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve there.  For my case this is early enough to load my reference.

However, please note that the addin can still try to load your assembly (and fail) if it needs it and this can happen even before Begininit. For example if you refer to an Enum or Const from your Assembly in the ThisAddin class.