# .Net 4.0 Linking, Assembly Resolution and VSTO 4.0

Tags: c#, .net, vsto, assembly-resolution, assemblyresolve

I'm having an assembly resolution problem with linked assemblies when writing a VSTO 4.0 add-in.

I have assemblies A, B, C and D; where Assembly A references B and B references C and D. During the build process I link assemblies C and D into assembly B. Then within assembly A we use two processes of redirecting assembly binding, both done in assembly A's static constructor.

1. From assembly A, hook into the `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += MyResolver` to redirect binding of C and D back into B (this dealt with 80% of use cases.)
2. Then to address the other 20% (or so I thought) from assembly A I call `Assembly.LoadFrom( <assembly B> )`

Now I've come across an issue where a VSTO 4.0 application is getting the following exception when trying to initialize an object from assembly A.

> Could not load file or assembly 'C, Version=#, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=#' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

When I look at the modules loaded into the AppDoamin I see assemblies A and B just as I do with an application that works properly; however, the `Appdomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve` event never fires, or at least my `private static Assembly MyResolver( Object sender, ResolveEventArgs args )` is never entered.

In my search the answer I found that seemed to be most in-line with my problem was here...

http://widequestion.com/question/vsto-assemblyresolve-issue/

All that being said his answer of, "There is no other way" seems... well, wrong but I can't disprove that. Is anyone aware of how I might be able to control assembly redirection in this context?

Comment: Did you ever solve this, Wes? I am experiencing similar problems with 2013/16 VSTO add-ins.

Comment: I did not, though I didn't spend much time on it. As far as I got was that I was not hooking into the main AppDomain's (in my case Excel) ResolveAssembly event. It appeared to me that plugin's were sand boxed but I never had time to confirm that.

Comment: For anyone landing here see my answer to a similar question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29675802/vsto-assemblyresolve-issue/62081064#62081064 - You use the Begininit to set up the AssemblyResolve event.